# How open ubuntu terminal in windows eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, ubuntu, terminal

I´m current using windows, but I have ubuntu installed as a subsystem. It´s possible that I open ubuntu terminal in Eclipse rather than open windows´s?

Comment: Do you mean in the [TM Terminal](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal#group-screenshots) view?

Comment: I like to change the terminal that TM Terminal open. Like in VS Code that I can set the terminal that it opens. I like to set that TM Terminal opens the ubuntu subsystem rather opens cmd

Comment: If you want to use a _SSH Terminal_ (which is provided by TM Terminal) for that, you have to install a SSH server into the Ubuntu subsystem: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html.en